# Upload javascript file to sharepoint online library saved in wrong format

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, jquery, ajax

I am trying to Upload a myfile.min.js to sharepoint online using JavaScript using JSOM but its stored as wrong encosing format

```
var req = jQuery.ajax({
             url: sourceFileItem + '?ver=' + ((new Date()) * 1), // add unique query string variable to prevent browser caching issues
             type: 'GET',
             cache: false,
             dataType: 'text',
             contentType :'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
         }).done(function (contents) {
             ajaxDeffer.resolve({ 'url': sourceFileItem, 'contents': contents });
.................etc
var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();     
        createInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
        for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
           createInfo.get_content().append(contents.charCodeAt(i));               
        }

        createInfo.set_overwrite(true);
        createInfo.set_url(sourceFileUrl.substring(sourceFileUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
 ...etc
  context.executeQueryAsync(
```

**the original content :**
 "False-positive on some BlackBerry 6.0 builds -

**the result content for the file** 
[image]

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by switching to use Rest API :)

```
 var fileContentUrl = appweburl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + finalFolderUrl + "')/Files('" + fileName + "')/$value";


         var info = {
             url: fileContentUrl,
             method: "GET",
             //headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": formdigest },
             binaryStringResponseBody: true,
             success: function (data) {
                 //binary data available in data.body                   
                 ajaxDeffer.resolve({ 'url': sourceFileItem, 'contents': data.body });
             },
             error: function (err) {
                 ajaxDeffer.reject();
             }
         };
         executor.executeAsync(info);
```

---

```
 executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + filesFolderPath + "')/Files/add(url='" + fileName + "',overwrite='true')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
                method: "POST",
                body: sourceFileItem.contents,
                //contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                timeout: 100000,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": formdigest/*, "content-length": contents.length */ },
                success: function () {
                    uploadedFilesCount = uploadedFilesCount + 1;
                    var countMsg = uploadedFilesCount + ' from ' + files.length + ' files Uploaded!';
                    // ...and we're done
                    $('#' + messageElement).text('upload ' + sourceFileUrl + ' done.    ' + countMsg);
                    sourceFileItem.contents = null;
                    ajaxDeffer.resolve();

                },
                error: function (sender, args) {
                    debugger;
                    sourceFileItem.contents = null;
                    ajaxDeffer.reject();
                }
            });
```